# View is not calling Using Codiegniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, view

I have placed view outside of mu current application folder and from there view for user is working but for admin panel it says :
 `Unable to load the requested file: backend/templates/header_assets.php`

Application Structure :

```
 -Example.com
  --application
  --system
  --index.php

-Example.com_views
 --index.php
 --blog.php
 --about.php
 --backend
   --login.php
   --dashboard.php
   --templates
     --header_assets.php
     --footer.php
```

View folder configure in index.php :

```
$view_folder = '../Example.com_views/views';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are call view file like that.

```
$this->load->view('backend/templates/header_assets');
```